# What is the difference between stream and pipe in C

Tags: c, multiprocessing, ipc

In Inter Process Communication(IPC), to communicate with each process "PIPE" that OS provides should be needed. And to transmit data from Input unit to program or from program to Output unit "Stream" that OS provides should be needed.

Here are my questions.

1. Are there differences between PIPE and Stream??
2. If they are different, because their functions are very similar isn't it more useful using only "PIPE" or "Stream" to transmit data??

Answer (score 3):

A pipe is a communication channel between two processes. It has a writing end and a reading end. When on open one of these two end, one get a (writing or reading) stream. So in a first approximation there is a stream at each end of a pipe.

So to set up an IPC, you should

- create a pipe using the function `pipe`. This return two `int`s identifying the two ends of the pipes;
- usually fork to get two processes;
- open each end of the pipe (usually in a different process after forking) and get two corresponding streams.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html